# Cannot resume game after pausing

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm having issues resuming my game after pausing. It seems like the code never reads my else statement but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've tried to use different keys and even clicking to pause/resume. I've also tried to add a function in both the create function and the update loop but I get the same issue from both.

```
this.input.keyboard.once('keydown_ESC', function () {
    if (game.scene.isActive('default')){
      game.scene.pause('default');
    } else {
      game.scene.resume('default');
    }
});
```

I expect the game to resume after pressing the esc key a second time.

Comment: are you sure that `game.scene.isActive('default')` is false when the game is paused? try to print something on `else` statement to see if you reach it the second time you press escape

Comment: The above `keyboard` event will run only `once`. You can maintain the count of `esc` key press and call the `resume` when the count is multiple of 2.

Comment: @Olympiloutre i have added a console.log to the else statement and it doesn't log anything on the second press.

Comment: So thats your problem, `game.scene.isActive('default')` is strill `true` when the game is paused, so you never go to the `resume` method. Try to find a method like `game.scene.isPaused('default')` to replace isActive ( I am not from javascript so I cant help on that. Check the documentation )

Comment: @randomSoul I've tried tying a counter to the esc key like you suggested but it seems like all inputs freeze when I pause. Further presses of the esc key don't make the count go up.

Comment: here is some readings maybe it helps http://ezelia.com/2013/pixi-tutorial ;)

Comment: @Olympiloutre i console.log'd `game.scene.isActive('default')` in chrome after pausing and it does come back false. Part of me feels like pausing it is causing all listeners to pause too

Comment: if you say it does come back false, then the listener is still active.. not sure if I get you well on this, have you tried to find another method like `isPaused` rather than `isActive` ? My guess it that `isActive` is true whether the game is paused or not

Comment: I have tried multiple methods including `isPaused`, however, they all come back with an error saying they aren't functions. One interesting thing is that if i type `game.scene.pause('default')` and `game.scene.resume('default')` into the chrome console, it successfully pauses and unpauses. However, if I pause it with the esc key and manually type `game.scene.resume('default')` it does not unpause. Could it be getting stuck on the first if statement?

Comment: Also `isActive` is true when the game is running and false when paused so it seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the scene becomes inactive altogether, thus no function in it will run. In other words this scene's code dead stops from running. So you need some other part of the game, which will remain active (e.g running) to take over the 'resume' functionality. Without me being an expert in phaser 3. This is a workaround to achieve this by putting this inside your scripts but outside of any scene's class or code. Let's say you define your

```
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

inside the script called game.html. So in there and still inside the javascript tag put this:

```js
var global_scene_paused = false;
var global_time_paused = Date.now() - 10000;


function global_pause(scene){
     if(Date.now() - global_time_paused > 2000 && game.scene.isActive(scene)){
        game.scene.pause(scene);
                console.log('--------- global_pause called');
  global_time_paused = Date.now();
  global_scene_paused = scene;
     } 
}

// keyCode 80 : P. Will resume by pressing 'P'
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 80 && Date.now() - global_time_paused > 2000 && global_scene_paused) {
        game.scene.resume(global_scene_paused);
  console.log('+++++++++++ RESUME');
  global_scene_paused = false;
  global_time_paused = Date.now();
    }
});
```

Inside your scene add this call instead of pause:

```js
this.input.keyboard.once('keydown_ESC', function () {
       global_pause('default'); //will be unpaused in game.html
});
```